# iGraph 0.7.1 - C library - msvc | Build fails when invoking igraph_betweenness(...)

Tags: visual-c++, igraph

Thanks to [this](http://dungleba.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/installing-igraph-in-visual-studio-2013/) blog post I was able to build igraph.lib with msvc. Simple tutorial examples work, however, if I use the method igraph_betweenness(...), I get the following build errors. I can build and run my program without errors on Linux.

> igraph.lib(prpack.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl prpack::prpack_base_graph::~prpack_base_graph(void)" (??1prpack_base_graph@prpack@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl prpack::prpack_igraph_graph::~prpack_igraph_graph(void)" (??1prpack_igraph_graph@prpack@@QEAA@XZ)
>
> igraph.lib(prpack.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl prpack::prpack_igraph_graph::prpack_igraph_graph(struct igraph_s const *,struct igraph_vector_t const *,int)" (??0prpack_igraph_graph@prpack@@QEAA@PEBUigraph_s@@PEBUigraph_vector_t@@H@Z) referenced in function igraph_personalized_pagerank_prpack
>
> igraph.lib(prpack.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl prpack::prpack_result::~prpack_result(void)" (??1prpack_result@prpack@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __cdecl prpack::prpack_result::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_Gprpack_result@prpack@@QEAAPEAXI@Z)
>
> igraph.lib(prpack.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl prpack::prpack_solver::prpack_solver(class prpack::prpack_base_graph *,bool)" (??0prpack_solver@prpack@@QEAA@PEAVprpack_base_graph@1@_N@Z) referenced in function igraph_personalized_pagerank_prpack
>
> igraph.lib(prpack.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl prpack::prpack_solver::~prpack_solver(void)" (??1prpack_solver@prpack@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function igraph_personalized_pagerank_prpack
>
> igraph.lib(prpack.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class prpack::prpack_result * __cdecl prpack::prpack_solver::solve(double,double,double const *,double const *,char const *)" (?solve@prpack_solver@prpack@@QEAAPEAVprpack_result@2@NNPEBN0PEBD@Z) referenced in function igraph_personalized_pagerank_prpack

Comment: Probably the same as the issue outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579997/igraph-c-compiling-link-errors-in-visual-studio

Comment: Indeed, I should have found it earlier. However, it's a little bit disappointing that this workaround only works for release builds, so I can't use debugging tools at all.

Unfortunately, I'm not done yet, as GraphML support doesn't work for me. I am aware that I need to have the libxml2 library. After extraction to a specific path, I set the include and library directories in the solution properties. This configuration does not seem enough, as I still get the error:

Error at src\foreign-graphml.c:1211 :GraphML support is disabled, Unimplemented function call

Comment: I guess it should work for the debug build as well, just add the compiler option to the Debug configuration. Or, you could modify `config.h` and add `#define PRPACK_IGRAPH_SUPPORT 1` somewhere. For the GraphML support, you will also have to modify `config.h` and add `#define HAVE_LIBXML 1` to let the compiler know that `libxml` is available.